# wrong output for the below code

Tags: java

Output of this code supposed to start from 99 but it starts form 59. What is the reason for that?
Here the code

```
public class BeerSong {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 99;
        String word = "bottles";
        while (x > 0) {
            if (x == 1) {
                word = "bottle"; // singular, as in ONE bottle.
            }
            System.out.println(x + "" + word + " of beer on the wall");
            System.out.println(x + "" + word + " of beer.");
            System.out.println("Take one down.");
            System.out.println("Pass it around.");
            x = x - 1;
            if (x > 0) {
                System.out.println(x + "" + word + " of beer2 on the wall");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
            } // end else
        } // end while loop
    } // end main method
} // end class
```

Comment: [It does start from 99.](https://ideone.com/P2jnGR)

Comment: Is there a limit on how many lines your console displays?  Perhaps some of the song has scrolled off the top.

Comment: it runs correctly in netbeans but not in command prompt

Answer (score 0):

I think Dawood already gave the most plausible answer. Your output window is limited. I just executed your code in a Linux prompt, and when I scroll complete up, it really starts off 99.

[image]